# Using Jar.exe to create jar file

Tags: java, jar

During the build, I need to create Jar from command line. I have used http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html.

Q: Jar created by eclipse having org\eclipse\jdt\internal\jarinjarloader\ folders strucure (which includes .class files), Yet, Jar created using the Jar.exe - not. 
I'm using this command line

```
jar cfm Myjar.jar Manifest.txt bin -C ExternalJars .
```

Comment: What output do you see from running that command line?

Comment: Don't do this manually. Use Maven or Gradle to handle it all for you.

Comment: the docu (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) states, that if you add a "." after the dir as you did, no hirarchy is preserved.